# How can I adjust the UVs of my quad so my texture isn't flipped?

Tags: libgdx, matrix, uv-mapping

My sprite geometry is reversed using matrix so that it is in the XZ plane. This results in the image used for the sprite to also be reversed, which I don't want:

[image]

(source : http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2032 )

The image is then upside-down (note the 2 and 4):

[image]

Would you know how to switch the UVs, or apply a matrix on the image only?

Here is my code to draw the new image (the broken one):

```
curPix.drawPixmap(modelPix, newX, newY, modelX, modelY, tileResolution, tileResolution);
```

This is how the plane is modified in "render:"

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
batch.setTransformMatrix(matrix);
batch.begin();
getMap(0).draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you're just seeing the back of the quad, which will be the reverse of the front.

To fix this, simply rotate -90 degrees about the z-axis, so the quad is facing up instead of down. You'll have to move it down the x plane a little after that though.

Otherwise you can rotate the quad 90 degrees about the z-axis, and then 180 degrees about the x-axis to get it facing up. You probably shouldn't mess around with the UV coordinates if you're using a spriteBatch interface.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work with TextureRegion and its method flip(boolean x, boolean y). Thanks for the answer